# Split game loop and render in JavaFX simulation

Tags: java, javafx, game-loop

I'm running a game/simulation on JavaFX and when I started it seemed reasonable to add an `AnimationTimer` to perform the tick updates. My `Entity`'s are composed of a `Polygon` that holds their shape and position. I added the `Polygon`'s to the scene via a `Group` and everything renders like magic. However, since it's an simulation, I now want to run millions of ticks with no rendering, to advance to the future and see the results. The problem is, since my `Entity`'s (x,y) positions are inside the Polygon, every time `handle()` is called in the animation, it seems that the screen is updated.

What is the proper way to split the game loop and render, to be able to call render only after some amount of ticks?

I thought of creating my own MyPolygon class to hold the simulation data, and then when the time comes to draw, create on the fly one Polygon per Entity, but that seems also overkill for me (but maybe I'm wrong).

Also, I'm not sure how to change the ticks per second rate on the AnimationTimer. So I'm not sure it is suited for this specific need.

It seems like a very simple design choice, so there has to be a proper way to do it with JavaFX...

Comment: You have misunderstood the `AnimationTimer` a little. JavaFX maintains a thread (the FX Application Thread) that processes user input (handles events) and on every "pulse" renders the UI to the screen. If there are `AnimationTimer`s running, their `handle(...)` methods are invoked exactly once on every pulse. So, in other words, rendering the UI triggers the call to `handle(...)`, not the other way around. JavaFX aims to create a rendering pulse every 1/60 second. Recommended reading: [part1](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) and [part2](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html)

Comment: So you might want to just use a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) to run the simulation in a background thread, and use its `onSucceeded` handler to render the results when it's finished.